# How to use Alamofire to make a MailGun API call?

Tags: swift, curl, alamofire

I have been trying to make a MailGun API call to send an email from within my project: [MailGun message sending API documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api)
However, to no avail I don't seem to be able to make it work. I did successfully send an email through the terminal with the `curl` command, but when it comes to Alamofire I am stuck.

I need help translating this terminal code snippet:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

To a request using Alamofire.

My current faulty Swift code is:

```
let basicAuthentication = Request.authorizationHeader(user: "api", password: "mySecretApiKey")

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [(basicAuthentication?.key)!: (basicAuthentication?.value)!]
        let parameters: Parameters? = ["from": "mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME",
                                       "to": "destination@email.com",
                                       "subject": "Hello There!",
                                       "text": "This is sent from within a Swift project!"]


        Alamofire.request("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
            print(response)
        }
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried your code but at least your encoding is wrong. You're encoding your body as JSON and the curl code is using a form. URLEncoding.default should be the right value for the encoding parameter. After that, if it's still breaking, debug the response. I suggest you download Charles proxy to see if the requests curl and the iOS app send are any different and how.

Comment: @A.Jam glad I can help. I still suggest you check out charles if you plan on doing network calls. I seriously don't understand how people debug any network calls effectively without it or a similar tool.

Comment: I will for sure. Seems like a handy tool!

Comment: @FernandoMazzon Great call. It's unfortunate they don't put better iOS examples in their documentation. But you're my hero as well haha